# Big file in my /usr/share/nginx/ directory that keeps increasing, why?

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I'm new to ssh and vps management. In fact I had someone do the initial configuration and setting up my WordPress site, but I feel there is something wrong (Multiple things), because the site goes offline a lot and there is one thing I managed to notice via using "ncdu /" and that there is a big file called "on" inside /usr/share/nginx/ directory. It's almost 15GB in size now but it's increasing everyday, I think this is not normal right? What is this file and how to stop it? could it be the reason for the site down time?